# aiogram почему такая ошибка?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

bot = Bot('')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Здравствуй')
executor.start.polling(dp)
```

что делать? я установил вроде aiogram (делал по видео с ютуба которое было 10 мес назад опубликовано, может дело в версии?) ошибка:

```
  line 1, in <module>
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' (C:\storage\d\d1\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Потому что у тебя код для aiogram 2, а установил ты aiogram 3. В третьей версии нет executor

Comment: а как старую установить?

Comment: возможные дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ImportError%3A+cannot+import+name+%27executor%27+from+%27aiogram%27)

Comment: Как-то так: `pip install aiogram==2.25.1`.

Comment: выдало ошибку после установки `ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp Failed to build aiohttp ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`